# optimise scraping and requesting web page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-multithreading

How should I optimise my time in making requests

```
link=['http://youtube.com/watch?v=JfLt7ia_mLg',
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=RiYRxPWQnbE'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=tC7pBOPgqic'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=3EXl9xl8yOk'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=3vb1yIBXjlM'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=8UBY0N9fWtk'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=uRPf9uDplD8'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=Coattwt5iyg'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=WaprDDYFpjE'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=Pm5B-iRlZfI'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=op3hW7tSYCE'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=ogYN9bbU8bs'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=ObF8Wz4X4Jg'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=x1el0wiePt4'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=kkeMYeAIcXg'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=zUdfNvqmTOY'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=0ONtIsEaTGE'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=7QedW6FcHgQ'
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=Sb33c9e1XbY']
```

I have a list of 15-20 links of youtube search result of first page Now the task is to get the likes,dislikes,view count from each video url and for that what I had done is

```
def parse(url,i,arr):
    req=requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")#, 'html5lib')
    try:
        likes=int(soup.find("button",attrs={"title": "I like this"}).getText().__str__().replace(",",""))
    except:
        likes=0
    try:
        dislikes=int(soup.find("button",attrs={"title": "I dislike this"}).getText().__str__().replace(",",""))
    except:
        dislikes=0
    try:
        view=int(soup.find("div",attrs={"class": "watch-view-count"}).getText().__str__().split()[0].replace(",",""))
    except:
        view=0
    arr[i]=(likes,dislikes,view,url)
    time.sleep(0.3)

def parse_list(link):
    arr=len(link)*[0]
    threadarr=len(link)*[0]
    import threading
    a=time.clock()
    for i in range(len(link)):
        threadarr[i]=threading.Thread(target=parse,args=(link[i],i,arr))
        threadarr[i].start()
    for i in range(len(link)):
        threadarr[i].join()
    print(time.clock()-a)
    return arr

arr=parse_list(link)
```

Now I am getting the populated result array in about 6 seconds.Is there any faster way I can get my array(arr) so that it takes quite less time than 6 secs

my array first 4 elements look like so that you get a rough idea

```
[(105, 11, 2836, 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=JfLt7ia_mLg'),
 (32, 18, 5420, 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=RiYRxPWQnbE'), 
 (45, 3, 7988, 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=tC7pBOPgqic'),
 (106, 38, 4968, 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=3EXl9xl8yOk')]

Thanks in advance :)
```

Comment: If your code works, but you're looking for some improvements, you should ask your question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use multiprocessing Pool object for that particular case.

```
import requests
import bs4
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


links = [
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=JfLt7ia_mLg',
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=RiYRxPWQnbE',
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=tC7pBOPgqic',
 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=3EXl9xl8yOk'
]

def parse_url(url):
    req=requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")#, 'html5lib')
    try:
        likes=int(soup.find("button", attrs={"title": "I like this"}).getText().__str__().replace(",",""))
    except:
        likes=0
    try:
        dislikes=int(soup.find("button", attrs={"title": "I dislike this"}).getText().__str__().replace(",",""))
    except:
        dislikes=0
    try:
        view=int(soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "watch-view-count"}).getText().__str__().split()[0].replace(",",""))
    except:
        view=0
    return (likes, dislikes, view, url)

pool = Pool(cpu_count)   # number of processes
data = pool.map(parse_url, links)   # this is where your results are
```

This is cleaner as you only have one function to write and you end up with exactly the same results.

Comment: error :TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

This is not a workaround but it can save your script from using "try/except block" which definitely plays a role to somewhat slow the operation down.

```
for url in links:
    response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select("div#watch-header"):
        view = item.select("div.watch-view-count")[0].text
        likes = item.select("button[title~='like'] span.yt-uix-button-content")[0].text
        dislikes = item.select("button[title~='dislike'] span.yt-uix-button-content")[0].text
        print(view, likes, dislikes)
```

Comment: try,except are somewhat necessary for me to use in my program since some videos are also disabled to show likes and dislikes etc

Comment: But the links you have provided above have got no issues without them. I tested it..

Comment: Is this among them you pasted above?